# Notice: Undefined property: ADOFetchObj::$date_fin in [...]opensondage\fonctions.php on line 89

Tags: php, fetch, adodb

I'm trying to update code of opensondage from php 5 to php 7
I have this error

> Notice: Undefined property: ADOFetchObj::$date_fin in [...]opensondage\fonctions.php on line 89

This is the code :

```
function get_sondage_from_id($id)
{
    global $connect;

    // Ouverture de la base de données
    if(preg_match(";^[\w\d]{16}$;i",$id)) {
        $sql = 'SELECT sondage.*,sujet_studs.sujet FROM sondage
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sujet_studs ON sondage.id_sondage = sujet_studs.id_sondage
                WHERE sondage.id_sondage = '.$connect->Param('id_sondage');

        $sql = $connect->Prepare($sql);
        $sondage=$connect->Execute($sql, array($id));

        if ($sondage === false) {
            return false;
        }

        $psondage = $sondage->FetchObject(false);
        $psondage->date_fin = strtotime($psondage->date_fin);
        return $psondage;
    } 
return false;
}
```

Comment: Just for simplicity, which line in the 23 you show is line 89?

Comment: Is there a `date_fin` column in the `sondage` table?

Comment: Line is  89 $psondage->date_fin = strtotime($psondage->date_fin);

Comment: Yes there is a date_fin column in sondage

Comment: Well the error message suggests that there is not? Could it be a case issue?

Comment: No it's not suggested

Answer (score 0):

This code works, I changed the date manually, so their is no date_fin in the object I think

```
function get_sondage_from_id($id)
{
global $connect;

// Ouverture de la base de données
if(preg_match(";^[\w\d]{16}$;i",$id)) {
$sql = 'SELECT sondage.*,sujet_studs.sujet FROM sondage
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sujet_studs ON sondage.id_sondage = sujet_studs.id_sondage
        WHERE sondage.id_sondage = '.$connect->Param('id_sondage');

$sql = $connect->Prepare($sql);
$sondage=$connect->Execute($sql, array($id));

if ($sondage === false) {
  return false;
}

$psondage = '02/05/2020';
return $psondage;
}

return false;
}
```